# does anyone know the name of this program?

Tags: software-recommendation

Does anyone know the name of this program? Here are some pics. please help I have been looking for it non-stop over 2 weeks now. Please help!

Scroll through the album and if you know please tell me it's a program about Composing.

http://www.flickr.com/photos/41628139@N05/7769183380/in/photostream/lightbox/

Comment: The pictures don't seem to be uploaded. Could you please check?

Comment: @Rinzwind Ah...

Comment: ok basic questions: are you sure this is Ubuntu software? and can you add some detail on where you got the images from?

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is [Blender 3D](http://www.blender.org/).

> Blender is the free open source 3D content creation suite...

Here is one screenshot of Blender (to give you an idea of the general look of the software):

[image: Video editing with Blender 3D.]

Answer (score 1):

Based on the pictures, I could maybe say it's one of these three:

**Ardour** - http://ardour.org/

> Ardour is a multichannel hard disk recorder (HDR) and digital audio
>    workstation (DAW).  It can be used to control, record, edit and run
>    complex audio setups.

**Qtractor** - http://qtractor.sourceforge.net/qtractor-index.html

> Qtractor is an Audio/MIDI multi-track sequencer application... Target platform is Linux, where the Jack Audio Connection Kit (JACK) for audio, and the Advanced Linux Sound Architecture (ALSA) for MIDI, are the main infrastructures to evolve as a fairly-featured Linux desktop audio workstation GUI, specially dedicated to the personal home-studio.

**LAoE** - http://www.oli4.ch/laoe/home.html

> LAoE means Layer-based Audio Editor, and it is a rich featured graphical audiosample-editor, based on multi-layers, floating-point samples, volume-masks, variable selection-intensity, and many plugins suitable to manipulate sound, such as filtering, retouching, resampling, graphical spectrogram editing by brushes and rectangles, sample-curve editing by freehand-pen and spline and other interpolation curves, effects like reverb, echo, compress, expand, pitch-shift, time-stretch, and much more.

But the picture quality is so bad I am not at all confident. Could you give us more information? What exactly does it do? It runs on Macs, doesn't it? Where did you see it?